# Correct way to retrieve Firebase image on Swift project

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

Im setting up a project in which I would like to retrieve the data from the Firebase database and appear on the TableView. 
for the Strings I was able to retrieve but form image im having a really hard time , most for lack of knowledge from my end. The image from Firebase is being retrieved Firebase stage URL.

This is a Firebase project, NoSql and Swift.

File 1:

```
   fileprivate var items: [ItemInfo]! = [("Titulo","Description","email","Linkdetalhes","telefone","Coordenates","Rating","photo")]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    switch clickedButton {
    case 1:
        items.removeAll()


        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).fireBaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            let dictRoot = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            let dictAliances = dictRoot["Aliances"] as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
            print(dictAliances.count)
            //new strategy for image
            for key in Array(dictAliances.keys) {
                let alianceDic = dictAliances[key]


                self.items.append(( alianceDic!["Title"] as! String, alianceDic!["Description"] as! String, alianceDic!["email"] as! String, alianceDic!["Linkdetalhes"] as! String, alianceDic!["telefone"] as! String, alianceDic!["Coordenates"] as! String, alianceDic!["Rating"] as! String, alianceDic!["photo"] as! String))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print("**** \(self.items)")
            }
            print(dictAliances)
        })
        self.tableView?.reloadData()


   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hello", for: indexPath) as! itemTableViewCell

    let item = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.Title.text = item.Title
    cell.Description.text = item.Description
    cell.Rating.text = item.email

    cell.photo.text = item.photo
    return cell
}

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "exemplo"){

        let vc = segue.destination as! DetalhesViewController


        vc.titulodetalheProduto = self.escolhido.Title
        vc.descriptiondetalheProduto = self.escolhido.Description
        vc.emaildetalheProduto = self.escolhido.email
        vc.linkdetalhesProducto = self.escolhido.Linkdetalhes
        vc.telefonedetalheProduto = self.escolhido.telefone
        vc.locationdetalheProduto = self.escolhido.Coordenates
        vc.ratingdetalheProduto = self.escolhido.Rating
        vc.photodetalheProduto = self.escolhido.photo

    }
```

File 2:

```
@IBOutlet weak var photodetalhe: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titulodetalhe: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ratingdetalhe: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var telefonedetalhe: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emaildetalhe: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationdetalhe: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptiondetalhe: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var linkdetalhes: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    linkdetalhes.text = linkdetalhesProducto
    titulodetalhe.text = titulodetalheProduto
    ratingdetalhe.text = ratingdetalheProduto
    telefonedetalhe.text = telefonedetalheProduto
    emaildetalhe.text = emaildetalheProduto
    locationdetalhe.text = locationdetalheProduto
    descriptiondetalhe.text = descriptiondetalheProduto
    photodetalhe.image = photodetalheProduto
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

result expected is to collect data from the photo on the database and fill in the UIIamge on the Swift project

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1vrjt7Nvb0&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq&index=5) should solve your problem.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. It looks like your loading a string from Firebase and calling it a photo `alianceDic!["photo"] as! String` and then later assigning that string to a field in the tableView cell `cell.photo.text = item.photo`. Not sure what you're trying to do there. What you should be doing is retrieving the the photo URL for a photo that's saved in Firebase Storage. Then, once you have the URL, retrieve the photo and store it in your Item object for display in the tableView. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: hi Jay, thank you for your comment, the ideia with the "photo" is to retrieve an image URL from Firebase, at this point in time I don't know how to do the same.

Comment: Ok. When responding to comments be sure to tag the person you are responding to with and at symbol followed by their name - like this @IsidoroDaSilvaJr. so we will be notified. You comment leads to more questions: Are you able to store the URL string in Firebase? If so, does the URL string come from storing your image in Firebase [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)? If so, did you go through the [Download Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) section of the Storage Getting Started Guide? If so, where are you stuck? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay thanks for the advise. I was able to fix the issue ..will share the same as soon my Xcode finishes Updating.